# Active Directory User Copy within the same domain/forest

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain, user-accounts, copy

we have set up Active Directory Replication within the same domain/forest between two Windows Servers 2012. The Master Server, copies its contents to the secondary server. Unfortunately, for a number of users, instead of creating the user on the master server, we created the user on the secondary server.

Is there a way to manually copy each account from the secondary server to the Master server?

Comment: What is the actual problem? In a std config it shouldn't really matter if a user was created on the primary DC or the secondary DC as far as I know.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please give us more details.

Comment: There is no primary/secondary concept for DCs. They may hold different FSMO, but all DCs have same data for same domain. Sounds like you have replication issue?

Comment: The problem is that when I go to the primary DC, the user doesn't appear there, but only on the secondary server were it was created. The replication is set one way: from the primary DC to the secondary DC, so replication works alright (i just checked it - created a user on the master instantly copied to the other), but one way.

Comment: scratch that... I had the console open for a while and it wasn't refreshing. I had to close and reopen it... then the user appeared.

Answer (score 0):

The console was left open and it had to be closed and reopened for the user to appear. Notjusttime, as well as Strongline have made it clear that sync works both ways.